# react number input and floating point precision

Tags: reactjs, forms, precision, tofixed

I'm making a form, one input is a weight, in the format 'd.ddd'

I have tried a few things, from the .toFixed(3) method, to adding in a bunch of properties on the input element...

```
<input 
    type="number" 
    step="0.001" 
    min="0.001"
    max="10"
    precision={3} 
    name ="weightOfTenPieces" 
    onChange={(e)=>handleFormInput(e)} 
    value={formState.weightOfTenPieces||""}
/>
```

```
    function handleFormInput(e){
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value =e.target.value;
        setFormState(prevState=>{
            const newState = {...prevState,[name]:value};
           return newState
        })
     }
```

I have tried putting toFixed(3), but that results in a loss of focus.

```
inputting 0.340 results in
0.3400000035762787
```

first attempt - failure:

```
    function handleFormInput(e){
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value =e.target.value;
        console.log(name,value);
        let safeValue = value;
        if(name =="weightOfTenPieces"){
            console.log("safe value is:");
            safeValue=Number(value).toFixed(2);
            console.log(safeValue);
        }


        setFormState(prevState=>{
            const newState = {...prevState,[name]:safeValue};
            console.log(newState);
           return newState
        })
        console.log(formState);
     }

//results in input focus loss. not acceptable.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix the number of decimal digits using `toFixed`

```
const value = Number(e.target.value).toFixed(3);
```

Then in order to remove unwanted zeros at the end of number and preventing input losing focus, assign the value to state as below:

```
this.setState({ value: Number(value) });
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-moon-z1q3n?file=/index.js:369-414)